# My 360 video doesn't show but the audio of it works when using the plugin

Tags: vimeo

This is the message I get from the console:
Unexpected timestamp values detected. This can occur in H.264 videos not encoded with the baseline profile. Timestamps will be skewed to correct the playback for (link to the video)

The thing is: the videos are all in mp4 and I got them from the client who doesn't know anything about them but that they need it in 360.

What can I do to fix it?

Thanks,